# Android can't boot -- displays booting splash until battery drains

Tags: boot

My Android can't boot.  It displays the booting splash (a sci-fi planet-like image) until the battery drains.

Is this condition what's referred to as a `boot loop`?  Is there any chance to recover?

The condition came gradually. Each new time booting, it would take longer but it would eventually boot. As of yesterday, it can't get through the boot step and just stays there until the battery is out.

Another thing that was happening in the last couple of weeks is that the phone would randomly (on its own, without user interference) go out (but not power itself off) for like 10-15 min at a time, pressing power wouldn't do anything, then it would wake up and the 4G service would be reinstated.

The hardware is a `Motorola Razr Bionic`.

I also tried going into the recovery mode but all it did was display an android robot lying down with a ! (exclamation mark) sign above it for a few minutes, then went back to the splash screen hanging again.

I also tried following [these instructions](http://bombshelltech.wordpress.com/2013/03/22/motorola-droid-razr-factory-reset/) (Alternate Method) but I am stuck in part 5:  I press volume up/down but it doesn't change the lying android with an exclamation mark.  Eventually, it goes into the infinite boot splash and I have to take the battery out to get out of it and power it off.

Comment: Well, more information is needed to answer your question. Did you root/flash your device or what happened before you first encoutered this problem?

Comment: no.  the condition came gradually.  each new time booting, it would take longer.  but it would eventually boot.  as of yesterday, it can't get through the boot step and just stays there until the battery is out.  another thing that was happening in the last couple of weeks is that the phone would randomly (on its own, without user interference) go out (but not power itself off) for like 10-15 min at a time, pressing power wouldn't do anything, then it would wake up and the 4G service would be reinstated.  not sure if this is related.

Comment: can you post the model of the device?

Comment: it is a Motorola Razr Bionic

Comment: I also tried going into the recovery mode but all it did was display an android robot lying down with a ! (exclamation mark) sign above it for a few minutes, then went back to the splash screen hanging again.

Comment: Could you try hard reset mentioned [here?](http://www.droidforums.net/forum/droid-bionic-tech-support/170155-how-hard-reset-droid-bionic.html). I am sure you would have tried mutliple methods, it might help.

Comment: did it but the problem remains...